# How to server inputStream from URL in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, java-io

I am trying to build a Spring controller to serve a file from a url:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getFile () throws IOException {
     CommonHttpClient client = new CommonHttpClient();
     URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
     InputStream stream = url.openStream();
     final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
     headers.add("Content-Type", "text/html");
     return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(IOUtils.toByteArray(stream), headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

I have ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter in my AnnotationMethodHandlerAdaptor in bean configuration.

However, when I call this page, I am getting nonsensical strings like
"PHBYzT5QB...."
The url is definitely reachable and no IOException were thrown.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mixing few things here. If the file you want to serve available on your local file system then you don't need to read from URL. If you define your method signature with HttpResponse parameter you will be able to get OutputStream and write to it. No converters should be necessary - just read from one stream (file) and write to the other in a loop. It is also important to set correct content type header in response.

```
@RequestMapping...
public void getFile(HttpResponse resp) throws IOException {
  InputStream is = ... // get InputStream from your file
  resp.setContentType("text/html"); // or whatever is appropriate for your file
  OutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream();
  // now read from one stream and write to the other
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int len = in.read(buffer);
  while (len != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    len = in.read(buffer);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Sorry for any confusion, the file is indeed an a server.  I will replace this with www.google.com to make it clear.  IOUtils.toByteArray does exactly the same thing as your code and I have also set the content-type.

Comment: Wow, I should have stayed with the basic.  Using HttpResponse does indeed work.  I will award you the answer later, but i want to see how this could be done with ResponseEntity<byte[]> since it is mentioned in many source i have read.

Comment: Even if approach with ResponseEntity works I think it would be inferior to working with streams as whole file would need to be kept in memory at the same time, which would be undesirable or impossible for large files or more than trivial requests rate

Comment: + plus parameter should be HttpServletResponse (not HttpResponse), but otherwise works!

Answer (score 0):

i think this is BASE encoded byte array